# TSQL - Group Sales_Rep rows to columns and display DESCRIP column as rows No aggregate

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have the below query.. I need to list the sales rep as columns and the information in the DESCRIP under the appropriate sales rep.  Pivot doesn't work as I am not aggregating anything.  Haven't found something that is clicking with me so I am asking for your help..  Thank you for your time.

```
SALES_REP   DESCRIP
AG  (AXI01) EGCG EXTENDED RELEASE CAPSULES (RD)
AG  (DLI01) NWE-01 ESSENTIAL DIGESTIVES ()
AG  (KID01) KIDNEYHOOD S3 (UT)
AG  (AXI01) AB-4166 DISSOLUTION TESTING (RD)
AG  (AXI01) MCC SPHERES COATED W BLACK IRON OXIDE (RD)
AG  (ELY01) MATTER REFORMULATION (RON/A)
BD  (SMA01) VEGETARIAN PROTEIN BLEND W/GREENS  (RD)
BD  (MIT01) ARGIINE AAKG GARN AND TABLETS (ANGEL)
BD  (DLI01) BISMUTH/FURAZOLIDONE/CLARITHROMYCIN COMBINATION DRUG PRODUCT_UTECH GUM (NL)
BD  (00390) COAT 8 KILOS OF TABLET CORES WITH ABOUT 1 % COATING THAT HAS ADDED  SAFETRACES DNA MARKER   ()
BD  (EEX02) GRANULATE SOY PROTEIN WITH ACACIA  ()
BD  (LIQ01) GRANULATE SAMPLES WITH WATER ONLY , SPRAY DRIED LEMON, ORANGE , GRAPEFUIT POWDERS. BASE ALREADY CONTAINS 25-30% ACACIA GUM ()
BD  (BRA01) FOR QUOTING PURPOSES , DEVELOP FORMULA FOR DEXBROMPHENIRAMINE MALEATE 2 MG AND PHENAZOPYRIDE HCL (AZO) 100 & 200 MG TABS ()
CB  (NUS04) JUNGAMALS JAPAN 2021 25 BOTTLE R&D PILOT FOR STABILITY TESTS (ANGEL)
CB  (NUS01) US DIGESTIVE 90 COUNT VERSION OF NUS292C (ANGEL)
CB  (LIM01) QUICK DISSOLVE TABLET - RTA SHOT (BERRY) (UT)
CB  (LIM01) QUICK DISSOLVE TABLET - THRIVE-HGH (TROPICAL) (UT)
CB  (AMB01) AMBRA/LOVIDIA XR FORMULA WITH GYMNEMA SLYVESTRE 465 MG (RD)
CB  (SHA02) RITESTART KIDS & TEENS REFORMULATION (UT)
CB  (BAS01) SEROVITAL B CAPSULE FORMULA OPTIONS - YELLOW PWDR IN CLEAR & "00" WHITE CASPULE SAMPLES (USHA)
CB  (NUS01) TR90 FIT US PLACEBO 20 KG RUN 60 CNT APPROX 600-700 UNLABELED BOTTLES (ANGEL)
MG  (AME02) POWDER BLENDING (ANGEL)
MG  (ZER01) CHRONDOITIN SULFATE COATING X2 (AG)
MG  (ELU01) TOBRAMYCIN GRANULES (NL)
MG  (BRI01) BRILLIANT HEALTH TRANSMIT GRAN AND TABLET (UT)
RND (DLI01) EFFERVESCENT PAIN PROCESS VALIDATION (RD)
RND (DLI01) GRAN D MAGNET QUALIFICATION (RD)
RND (DLI01) BLENDER CAPACITY STUDY (RD)
RND (DLI01) COATING PAN A&B QUALIFICATION (RD)
RND (WYE06) SODD-006 STABILITY EVALUATION (NL)
RND (WYE06) CAL160 PROCESS VALIDATION (RD)
SH  (LIV02) FORMULATION OF HYDRATION DRINK MIX (USHA)
SH  (KOB01) ASPIRIN CAFFEINE POWDER (USHA)
SH  (COP01) APPLE CIDER VINEGAR EFFERVESCENT TABLETS (USHA)
SH  (COP01) SURVIVAL TABLETS 720CT (NATE)
SH  (USA01) GRANULATE 10 KILO POWDER BLEND - USANA (USHA)
TV  (LIF01) PETANDIM LIF-07T AND LIF-13T NEW OMEGA (ANGEL)
TV  (LIF01) L-CARNITINE ISSUE NRF1 JP (ANGEL)
TV  (SHA01) SOY-02 REPLACEMENT IN SHK-06 AND SHK-22/25 PRODUCTS (AG)
TV  (ELY01) PROBIOTIC CAPSULES ()
TV  (VYM01) VYMUNE CHEWABLE TABLETS (UT)
TV  (QUL01) IMMUNITY BOOSTER (UT)
TV  (DOT01) DOT-06 UPDATED FORMULA WITH NEW OIL, STEVIA @ 95% NEED 2 OPTIONS ()
TV  (DOT01) MITO2MAX ()
TV  (DOT01) TERRAZYME ()
TV  (LIF02) GRANULATE 2 PREBLENDED POWDER PRODUCTS , PARTYAID AND FOCUSAID . USE WATER ONLY ()
TV  (PAR01) CALCIUM CITRATE WITH PROBIOTIC STICKPACK ()
```

```
SELECT        SALES_REP, '(' + CUSTOMER_ID + ') ' + PROJECT_DESCRIPTION + ' (' + IsNull(RD_REP,'') + ')' as DESCRIP
FROM            DLI_RND_PROJECTS
WHERE        (STATUS = N'OPEN')
ORDER BY SALES_REP
```

So something like this

```
AG           BD            CB        ETC
-------------------------------------------------
AXI01...      SMA01...      NUS04...
DLI01...      MIT01...      NUS01...
KID01...      DLI01...      LIM01...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select max(case when sales_rep = 'AG' then col end) as ag,
       max(case when sales_rep = 'BD' then col end) as bd,
       . . . 
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by sales_rep, col order by col) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (substring(descr, 2, 5))) v(col)
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: What if the amount of sales reps change?  More of a dynamic way so they query doesn't have to be changed each time?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Mark . . . You would have to construct the query dynamically if you don't know the list of sales reps *a priori*.